# What influence did Byun have on Reaper changes?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

I've heard it a few times over the years by now, by different casters (Lowko likes to mention it a lot): They claim is that that the player [Byun](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/ByuN) was single-handedly responsible for nerfs on the Reaper, due to how well he was able to control them.

My questions generally are: Is that accurate? What changes specifically could be linked to Byun's games (which versions)? Did Blizzard ever hint at him being the reason for a change (I assume they would never directly name a player, but maybe they mentioned something like "due to recent tournament results")? Which games could've been the reason for the changes?

Overall, it just comes across as a very weird claim, that *one player* alone was the catalyst for a unit nerf - instead of many pro players as a whole. I would like to know where this general idea comes from, or what could've given the impression that Byun was that player.

Perhaps some SC2 tournament historians know more :)

Comment: Byun was the first pro to really figure out how to abuse reapers. To everyone's collective memory, nerfs to the reaper came before other pros even caught up to his style, hence the claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they refer to [his performances](https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/5x59ts/byun_the_reaper_god_iem_katowice_sc2/) in high level tournaments like IEM Katowice.

After that, the Reaper KD8 charge has been nerfed twice.

In the [Balance Update of March 2017](https://news.blizzard.com/en-us/starcraft2/20562669/legacy-of-the-void-balance-update-march-7-2017) the cooldown has been increased from 7 seconds to 14 seconds.

In the [Balance Update of July 2017](https://news.blizzard.com/en-us/starcraft2/20950472/legacy-of-the-void-balance-update-july-2017) the damage was reduced from 10 to 5.

I'm not aware about any official statement about Byun in particular.